# Quarkus uber/fat jar name: does not respect project.build.finalName in version 1.13.3.Final as doc suggests

Tags: quarkus

I find that Quarkus uber/fat jar name is not controlled by `project.build.finalName` in version 1.13.3.Final, but by `<quarkus.package.output-name>` or property `quarkus.package.output-name`. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fast-jar` indeed does not respect this proprerty because everything it generates is put into a dedicated directory with a fixed name.

If the `uber-jar` is not respecting the property,then yeah that's a bug and please report

Comment: OK, reported as https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/18316. Thanks.

Comment: The ticket was closed because if output-name is there, will take priority; if removed, will take `final-name`, so dev team does not consider it's a bug. For me somehow it is bug, but if ppl are aware of this and know what to do, ok for me to close.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties

```
quarkus.package.type=uber-jar
quarkus.package.runner-suffix=runner
quarkus.package.output-name=custom_name_jar
```

Comment: Sorry but I already know that output-name is respected. I want to know why `final-name` is not respected. Does not answer the question(why when both are there, `final-name` is not respected)